# Mostrando errores en Rails con Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Tengo un formulario con ajax que lo muestro en un modal, pero si este modal no cumple con los requisitos no pasa el form, pero no muestra cuales son los errores del formulario, espero puedan ayudarme:

**contacts/shared/_error.html.erb**

```
<div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @contact from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
   <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     <li><%= message %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

**contact_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <h6>Formulario de contacto</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<%= form_for @contact, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
<% if @contact.errors.any? %>
<% end %>


  <div class="expanded row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Correo electronico" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: "Telefono de contacto" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="expanded row">
    <div class="input-group small-12 columns">
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Titulo del mensaje" %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group small-12 columns">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Contenido del mensaje", :rows => 10, :cols => 120 %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="actions small-12 columns">
      <%= f.submit "Enviar mensaje", class: "button" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @contact.errors? %>
  $("#error_explanation").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/error" %>');
<% else %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
  $(".notice").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts" %>');
  alert("Success!");
<% end %>
```

**contact_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contacts }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Pero te está mostrando algún error de ejecución? Es solo al mostrarte los errores de formulario que no funciona? Por ejemplo, ese `alert("Success!");` se ejecuta? Has revisado en la consola de chrome (o del explorador que uses) lo que te retorna el servidor al realizar la llamada asíncrona?

Comment: Hola @AlterLagos el alert si funciona, pero el render a notice no funciona, es decir que si hay un error no me muestra los mensajes de error ajax, pero si es exitoso el alert logra funcionar, ya que no logro hacer que el mensaje flash venga por ajax